# CSS | Navbar buttons aren't the same size as navbar

Tags: css, navbar

Well i've been working on a navigation bar for my Buycraft website and I can't seem to get the navbar buttons to be the same height as the navbar. I've looked it up on Google for a few days now and everything I've tried doesn't seem to work, or I just can't comprehend what to do. I've tried adding padding-top and padding-bottom and well the button centers itself of course as it should, but the button height seems to stay at 40px all the time. I want the button height to be 80px just like the navbar itself but I just can't seem to figure it out. If anyone could help I'd genuinely appreciate it! The navbar should have a somewhat like padding-top and -bottom to be 80px and atm its 40px for the buttons, so all together I suppose the navbar is actually 200px, correct me if i'm wrong.

Website: http://donate.casualsb.com/

(In the code I have down already, the navbar has no padding on it)
Code: http://pastebin.com/Li4GtyYP

Comment: change this line `li {
    line-height: 20px;
}` to `li {
    line-height: 80px;
}` in your style.css

Comment: It appears that your bootstrap library could be causing a conflict. On an IE browser I had better results changing the li line-height to 60px (it centered the text vertically and didn't hang below the UL object). What might work better is to set the container height to 80 (which I've seen you already did) then set interior heights to 100% so that they resize with the outer container.

Comment: After trying out a few more things I found out line-height was something I needed. It worked of course, so I came back here to say I found out, and it turns out shehary said it aha. Thank you both for answering ^-^